# Does Linux system load account for throttling of the Completely Fair Scheduler?

Tags: linux, load, cgroups, cfs

On Linux, system `load` is defined as the exponentially decaying average of 
  [`num runnable processes + num uninterruptable processes`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.7/kernel/sched/loadavg.c#L19-L28).  I am wondering if it will correctly account for [CFS cgroup quota](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-bwc.txt) used to  limit the number of cpu shares a group of processes may use in a given interval.

In other word: If a process is throttled due to depleted CFS quota, is it still considered runnable and therefore reflected in the system load average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found in this article on [Per-entity load tracking](https://lwn.net/Articles/531853/):

Throttled processes don't contribute to load. In a nutshell, every cgroup has its own per cpu run queue, and when the scheduler calculate the load of the whole system, it checks every queue and skips throttled processes.

---

*Credit for this answer goes to Haosdent Huang via the Mesos slack community chat.*